# Refactoring import statements using Shade relocations in Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-shade-plugin

I've been using Shade to relocate a dependency from `com.package.x` to `com.package.y`; when I build with Maven, it complains due to incompatible types - so I have to change my import statements inside my code to match `com.package.y`.

Is this really the only way to go about this? Changing the imports is making IntelliJ complain and basically breaks IDE integration. Is there no way Shade can modify the imports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main use case of the shade plugin is to generate an uber-jar while relocating some packages inside of it to prevent conflicts. As a rule you don't want to be developing against an uberjar.

If you actually do want to develop against your shaded jar (or you're solely using shade to relocate an existing jar), then you'll need to list your shaded jar as a  in lieu of the original jar, which I would imagine may need you to clean up a cyclic dependency.

Comment: yeah, I'm trying to bundle jackson with my jar (long story).

Comment: Your project should just use jackson normally at com.fasterxml.jackson (or whever it is these days), the shade plugin will take care of pointing all the code in your shaded uberjar at the relocated packages.

Comment: So you're saying that shade should automatically update the imports? Whenever I run my tests after doing so, it complains about type errors for my package vs com.fasterxml

Comment: Perhaps it's due to interdependency between modules?

Comment: It sounds like your shaded jar is showing up on the classpath of your tests.   As a general rule, I don't like for the exported shaded jar to be the same jar that has tests/etc/etc as it offers a tiny bit of abstraction in case I change my internal package structure. That's really the optimal thing to do, but I appreciate you may not be at that point; have you tried playing with the shadedArtifactAttached property; setting it to true?

Comment: @ldcmp I'm not entirely what I did incorrectly to start with; but I went back to what I had originally and started fresh, following your instruction. All good :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be fixed by seting **shadedArtifactAttached** to ***true*** in **configuration** tag.

```
<shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
```

Complete example and Reference: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/attached-artifact.html

I had the same issue and i fixed it by adding the above property. I am sharing my pom.xml of my shaded module just in case if you want to see any other tag values.

> pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.bitguiders.account.management</groupId>
      <artifactId>account-management</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.24-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
   <artifactId>account-management-metrics-lib</artifactId>
   <name>account-management-metrics-lib</name>
   <description>Bundled client library</description>
   <properties>
      <shaded.package>org.cas.osd.platform.ciam.shaded</shaded.package>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.cas.osd.platform.ciam.account.management</groupId>
         <artifactId>account-management-metrics</artifactId>
         <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>shade</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                     <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                     <promoteTransitiveDependencies>true</promoteTransitiveDependencies>
                     <createSourcesJar>true</createSourcesJar>
                     <relocations>
                        <!-- manually hide individual dependencies that a client might conflict with -->
                        <relocation>
                           <pattern>org.</pattern>
                           <shadedPattern>${shaded.package}.org.</shadedPattern>
                           <excludes>
                              <exclude>org.slf4j.**</exclude>
                              <exclude>org.xml.**</exclude>
                              <exclude>org.w3c.**</exclude>
                              <exclude>org.bitguiders.usagemetrics.**</exclude>
                              <exclude>org.bitguiders.**</exclude>
                              <exclude>org.bitguiders.**</exclude>
                              <exclude>org.apache.flume.**</exclude>
                              <exclude>org.apache.http.**</exclude>
                           </excludes>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                           <pattern>com.</pattern>
                           <shadedPattern>${shaded.package}.com.</shadedPattern>
                           <excludes>
                              <exclude>com.google.common.**</exclude>
                              <exclude>com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration</exclude>
                           </excludes>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                           <pattern>javassist</pattern>
                           <shadedPattern>${shaded.package}.javassist</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                           <pattern>javax.ws.rs</pattern>
                           <shadedPattern>${shaded.package}.javax.ws.rs</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                           <pattern>jersey.repackaged</pattern>
                           <shadedPattern>${shaded.package}.jersey.repackaged</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                           <pattern>net.</pattern>
                           <shadedPattern>${shaded.package}.net.</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                     </relocations>
                     <artifactSet>
                        <!-- these external dependencies should be exposed to clients -->
                        <excludes>
                           <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-api</exclude>
                           <exclude>org.bitguiders.cpp:cpp-product-usage-ingest-gateway-client</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                     </artifactSet>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```