# Adding HikariCP using maven caused ClassNotFoundException error

Tags: java, maven, hikaricp

while starting plugin for spigot server i have error when enabling HikariCP. I have Hikari shaded in my .jar. My pom.xml can be found here https://pastebin.com/3vpEzyig

```
[18:32:48] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling PvPCraftFactions v1.0.0 (Is it up to date?)
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig
        at com.massivecraft.factions.Settings.loadHikariConfig(Settings.java:411) ~[?:?]
        at com.massivecraft.factions.Settings.load(Settings.java:491) ~[?:?]
        at com.massivecraft.factions.P.loadSettings(P.java:197) ~[?:?]
        at com.massivecraft.factions.P.onEnable(P.java:153) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:340) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:357) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:317) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.s(MinecraftServer.java:414) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.k(MinecraftServer.java:378) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:333) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:263) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:525) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:101) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:86) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        ... 15 more
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to include the pom.xml instead of linking to Pastebin.

Comment: I'm sorry, i can't include pom.xml into the post, it would be too long in comparation with text.

Comment: Do you need hikari shadedPattern in maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the lines where your `com.zaxxer.hikari` package relocation from maven's pom.xml so `com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig` (and other classes) will be recognized.

```
<relocation>

  <pattern>com.zaxxer.hikari</pattern>
  <shadedPattern>com.massivecraft.factions.shade.com.zaxxer.hikari</shadedPattern>
</relocation>
```

See also usage of [refactoring imports when using shade relocations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807418/refactoring-import-statements-using-shade-relocations-in-maven).